# How to design API endpoints for resources that relate on eachother?

Tags: rest, api-design, node.js

I am developing REST API using node.js and Express.

I have `Houses` collection and `Rooms` collection. Every `Room` belongs to exactly one `House` for it's entire lifetime.

I'm not sure how to design API endpoints for managing `Rooms`. My problem is that if I use endpoints like `/houses/:house__id/rooms` for creating a room, getting all rooms or just one I still would need endpoints like `/rooms/:room_id` for deleting a room. It it okay to divide creating, returning and deleting of `Rooms` in such a way?

Or maybe I should structure my API in a way where `/rooms` would handle creating, deleting, modifying and getting one room but still keep `/houses/:house_id/rooms` so that all rooms for a house can be retrieved?

I'm fairly new when it comes to creating REST APIs and to be honest I didn't find any help in articles about best practices and such.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at this is to ask whether the system itself will need to deal with rooms outside of a house context.

If not, then APIs like `/houses/:id/rooms/:id` make sense and are natural. You can keep a good nesting and do PUT/GET/DELETE on the latter to alter a particular room of a house.

On the other hand if rooms can be dealt with outside of a house context. Like doing a search for all rooms in all houses which have an area larger than a certain size, then you need the form with `/houses/:id` and `/rooms/:id`.

REST guidelines won't really help that much - you're interested in how to structure the problem domain, whereas REST concerns will be several layers deep. But once you have a good structure, RPC or GraphQL is just as good.

In DDD terms, you're asking whether rooms and houses are different aggregates, or whether there's just a single one - the house, with an entity that's a room.